# C program looking to compute frequency and duty cycle for 555 Timer

Tags: c

Hi I keep getting an error message saying that my functions resistor and freqduty are not defined. I am confused on what this means. I am attaching my code and hopefully can be lead in the right direction as this is stumping me. Thanks. I declare and define the prototypes and call the functions so I am confused why the complier will not take this code and compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void resistor (void);
void freqduty (float ra, float rb, float c); // Prototype function for frequency and duty cycle
int main (void)
{
    int choice; // choice to run program from start menu or quit
    

    while (1)
    {
        // Menu for entering resistor and capacitor values
        printf("Welcome to the 555 Timer Frequency and Duty Cycle Calculator\n");
        printf("Please enter two resistor values in between ");
        printf("1 kOhms and 100 kOhms and a capacitor value\n\n");
        printf("Menu\n\n");
        printf("1. Continue\n");
        printf("2. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
  
        switch (choice)
            {
                case 1: resistor();
                    break;
                case 2: printf("Goodbye\n"); 
                    break;
                default: printf("Wrong Choice. Enter again\n");
                    break;
            } 
    
void resistor (void);

    float ra, rb, c; // Float variables for two resistor values and capacitor

    while(1) // While loop to gather resistor A value
    
    {
    
    printf("Enter a value for Resistor Ra (kOhms):  "); // First Resistor Value
    scanf("%f", &ra);
    
        if(ra < 1 || ra > 100) // Will repeat loop until value between 1 and 100 is entered
        
            printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
            
        else
        
            break; // breaks loop when valid data is entered
    
    }
    
    while(1)
   
    {
    
    printf("Resistor Rb (kOhms):  "); // Second Resistor Value
    scanf("%f", &rb);
    
        if(rb < 1 || rb > 100) // Will repeat loop until value between 1 and 100 is entered
        
            printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
            
        else 
        
            break; // breaks loop when valid data is entered
    
    }
    
    while(1)
   
    {
    
    printf("\nCapacitor (uF) :  "); // Capacitor Value
    scanf("%f", &c);
        
        if(c <= 0)
                
            printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
        
        else 
        {
            
            freqduty (ra, rb, c); // call function to compute frequency and duty cycle
            break; // break while loop and restart program from menu selection screen
    
        }
        
         break;
    }
    void freqduty (float ra, float rb, float c) // function to compute frequency and duty cycle
            {
            
                float freq, dutycyc, add; // Float variables for frequency and duty cycle equations
                
                freq = 2.0 * rb;
                add = (1.44 / (ra + ((2.0 * rb) * c))); 
                dutycyc = (rb / (ra + (2.0 * rb)));
    
                printf("\nThe frequency for these values entered is %.2f and the duty cycle");
                printf(" is %.2f \n\n", freq , dutycyc);    
                printf("%f     %f     %f", ra, rb, c);      
    
            }   
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error messages that you are getting.

Comment: C:\Users\malanska\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWCRzov.o Assignment 4 practice.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `resistor'

Comment: The compiler has told the correct message, functions `resistor` and `freqduty` are not defined, or do you put the definition in other files? Advise you to format the code with correct indentation that makes others and yourself read and check the code more easily.

Comment: The prototypes are placed before the main program begins which has worked in every other program I have written. I call the functions in the code as I have before.

Comment: The function **declaration** (prototype) is not the problem (the answer which makes this claim is wrong). The problem is the **function definition**. If you use a function that is not part of some library, then you must write it yourself somewhere.

Comment: @minimite do you forget to include the definition of `resistor` and `freqduty`?

Comment: I have both definitions in the code now

Comment: After my switch is the resistor function and at the end of the code is freqduty

Comment: After your switch statement, you have the following: `void resistor (void);` This is a function declaration, not a definition. Did you want to make it a definition? Then you must use an opening curly brace instead of a semicolon. But first you must close the `main` function, as local function definitions are not allowed. If you used proper indentation, then such errors would be easier for you to spot.

Comment: Wow that was a dumb mistake thank you. Also, my math in the function freqduty is not working. Any idea what could be happening there?

Comment: @minimite: What is your input, actual output and expected output of that function?

Comment: The values of ra, rb and c are transferring into the function but no math is being done

Comment: The values `ra`, `rb`, and `c`, are being printed in the third `printf` call of the function `freqduty`. The problem is the first two calls of `printf` in that function. In the first `printf` call, you use the `%.2f` specifier in the format string, so that the function expects a floating point value as an additional parameter. But in that function call, you do not supply any such parameter. In the second `printf` function call, you use the `%.2f` format specifier too, so it also expects one floating point value, but you supply it with two values instead.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the two functions at file scope. You defined the two functions inside function main(). This means that they are local to function main(), and invisible outside.

Also, at the point where they are are used, they are not defined yet.

Re-arrange the code and it has a chance to work.

---

I just noticed, they actually defined inside the while(1) inside main(), which is very unusual.